# Installing OpenMotif from CD to minimal CentOS OS

Tags: centos6, motif

I just did a minimal install of CentOS 6.7 (has to be 6.7) on a non-networked computer. I am now trying to

a) find a version of OpenMotif that is compatible with 6.7 (64 bit) and

b) install that version via CD or DVD image

Would appreciate all of the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the packages you need here: http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/.

Note that you probably also need some dependencies.  For a list of dependencies have a look at: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31367802/dir/centos_6/com/.